# How to set the datetime picker configuration from UTC to local in Ionic?

Tags: angular, cordova, datetime, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I use Ionic to create a mobile application and I have a little problem that I will explain to you.

I have a ion-datetime input.
When I open the picker, the default value on the picker delays by one hour compared to the real time.
When I display the date using DatePipe, the value is correct.

How to change the configuration of the ion-datetime input to display the local value of a Date and not the UTC value ?

For example:
- The current datetime on my computer is 17h18.
- The default value when I open the datetimepicker is 16h18.
- The value display by the DatePipe is 17h18 after have select a datetime using the picker.

How to have the same value for all ?

I show you my ion-datetime input:

```
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" 
                    pickerFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" 
                    min="1900" 
                    max="2100-12-31" 
                    formControlName="datetime" 
                    [(ngModel)]="rendezvous.datetime" 
                    cancelText="Annuler" 
                    doneText="Valider">
      </ion-datetime>
```

And how I display a date using DatePipe:

```
  <ion-item>
            Le {{rendezvous.datetime | date: "d/MM/y"}} à {{rendezvous.datetime | date: "HH:mm"}}
  </ion-item>
```

Ask me if you need more informations.
Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: did u fix this ?

Answer (score -2):

Duquesne follow below link for your purpose, you will get the answer with new ideas and new things.

**[NgBootstrap datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)**

This link will give you the knowledge for the date picker as well as more UI components that might help you in future eg.

- Date picker
- Accordion
- Alert
- Buttons
- Carousel
- Collapse
- Datepicker
- Dropdown
- Modal
- Pagination
- Popover
- Progressbar
- Rating
- Tabs
- Timepicker
- Tooltip
- Typeahead

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I won't a toolkit like Angular-Material.
With your datepicker it's 13h38 and on my computer it is 14h38.
I wan't the way to have the same hour on the ion-datetime input and the hour on my computer.